# processing json for stacked bar chart

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, d3.js

I'm new to javascript. I want to create a stacked bar or area chart over time, something similar to:
http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html

However, I'm not sure how to parse my json. Each date should be on the bottom, with the regions as the colored filter, the dates on the x-axis, the count for each region on the y-axis.

I think I need to make the region the key and the count the value, but not sure how to iterate over this and then also get the date. My data is coming from an ajax call, so I'm not processing in a .json file.

json sample:

```
[
    {
      "_id": {
        "Date": "2016-01-29",
        "Location": "30"
      },
      "counts": 25,
      "subcounts": [
        {
          "regions": "North America",
          "count": 3
        },
        {
          "regions": "Africa",
          "count": 2
        },
        {
          "regions": "South America",
          "count": 5
        },
        {
          "regions": "Asia",
          "count": 4
        },
        {
          "regions": "Europe",
          "count": 8
        },
        {
          "regions": "Australia",
          "count": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "Date": "2016-01-30",
        "Location": "30"
      },
      "counts": 20,
      "subcounts": [
        {
          "regions": "North America",
          "count": 2
        },
        {
          "regions": "Africa",
          "count": 3
        },
        {
          "regions": "South America",
          "count": 3
        },
        {
          "regions": "Asia",
          "count": 4
        },
        {
          "regions": "Europe",
          "count": 6
        },
        {
          "regions": "Australia",
          "count": 2
        }
      ]
    },
```

Comment: I think you will need to flatten your data, i.e. expand them to get an array of object with a date, regions, and count; then you can consider using [d3.stack](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#stack) to stack your data prior to creating the chart. If you submit a jsfiddle/plnkr, I can have a look and provide a more complete solution

Comment: I've never used jsfiddle! Actually right now I'm working on a flatten and map, so maybe I am on the right track

Comment: Simply go to https://jsfiddle.net/ . there you get one panel for html, one panel for css, and one panel for javascript. The last one is the output result :-)

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks!